# The Euler-Lagrange equations for rigid body rotation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

The  equations of motion  for rigid body rotation are:

$I\,\dot{\vec{\omega}}+\vec{\omega}\times I\,\vec{\omega}=\vec{\tau}$

How i can calculate this equations using  Lagrangian method ?

If i use 
$L=\frac{1}{2}\vec{\omega}^T\,I\,\vec{\omega}$

i don't get the right equations.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74742/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
S[ \omega, {\bf p},{\bf r}]= \int \left( \frac 12 I_1 \omega_1^2+ \frac 12 I_2 \omega_2^2+ \frac 12 I_3 \omega_3^2+{\bf p}\cdot (\dot{\bf  r}+\omega \times{\bf r}) \right)
$$
and vary all three vector variables ($\omega$, ${\bf p}$, and ${\bf r}$) to get an equation for each one. Then eliminate ${\bf p}$ and ${\bf r}$. You will end up with Euler's equations for  the angular velocity $\omega$.  Since this action is  linear in the time derivative $\dot {\bf r}$ it is a *Hamiltonian* action principle. The vector ${\bf p}$ is  Lagrange multiplier enforcing a *Lin constraint*. For more on Lin constraints see "Lin constraints, Clebsch potentials and variational principles" By Cendra and Marsden,  Physica D  27(1-2):63-89 (1987)

Comment: Check my signs! I may have an error. We want to get $\dot {\bf L}+ \omega\times {\bf L}$=0

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain why we have constraints?

Comment: No. Their origin is  complicated. You need to read Cendra and Marsden. It is interesting that these things were only understood in the mid 20th century despite action principles dating back to the 1700's.

Comment: I had forgotten that I answered this last year https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321836. My mind is going