# What is the symplectic form for rigid body systems?

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

I was pondering rigid body mechanics and the non-vanishing Poisson brackets $\left\{J_x,J_y\right\}=J_z$ etc. However in arbitrary coordinates $q^i$ with conjugate momenta $p_i$ we are supposed to have $\left\{q^i,q^j\right\}=\left\{p_i,p_j\right\}=0$ and $\left\{p_i,q^j\right\}=\delta_i^j$, so what is going on here? Can we express the poisson bracket in terms of $\phi^i,J_j$ coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

The symplectic manifold phase space for the classical version of the angular momentum algebra is the two-sphere $S^2$. The symplectic form , in terms of spherical polar angles $\theta$, $\phi$, is
$$
\omega = \sin\theta\, d\theta\wedge d \phi,
$$
i.e. the area 2-form for $S^2$. Then  we take 
$$
J_x= \sin\theta \cos \phi\\
J_y= \sin\theta \sin\phi\\
J_z= \cos\theta
$$
as the moment maps. 
Using hamilton's equations $dH= -\omega(V_H,-)$ with $H= J_x$, etc gives us
$$
V_{J_x}=\sin\theta \partial_\theta+\cos\phi \cot \theta \partial_\phi\\
V_{J_y}=-\cos\theta \partial_\theta +\sin\phi \cot \theta \partial_\phi\\
V_{J_z}= \partial_\phi.
$$
So from
$$
\{J_x,J_y\}= \omega(V_{J_x},V_{J_y})
$$
we read read off (after a bit of algebra) that
$$
\{J_x,J_y\}= \cos\theta =J_z.
$$
The other Poisson brackets work the same.

Incidentaly, there is a discussion of the Lagrangian formalism for the Euler equations of a rigid body at [Lagrangian of the Euler equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/321748/lagrangian-of-the-euler-equations/321836#321836)

Comment: Isn't the configuration space $SO\left(3\right)$? Also, I didn't phrase very well, but what I was really wondering is whether angular momentum is canonical momentum after a particular choice of coordinates, and if not, what is?

Comment: @Joshu Tilley. The configuration space of a rigid body top is $SO(3)$ and the associated phase space is 6 dimensional and has infinite volume. Both classical and  the quantum version of the top can have any value of  total angular momentum $J$.  The two dimensional $S^2$ is the phase space for a spin with a definite angular momentum $J$.    The spin  phase space must have finite volume becsue the quatum Hilbert space is finite dimensional.  I discussed the spin case in my answer because if you just want the Poisson brackets its symplectic geometry  is simpler  than the top.