# How to derive the free rigid body equations from Euler-Lagrange?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, rotational-dynamics, variational-principle, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm trying to retrieve the equations of motion for a free rigid body:
$$
I(t)\dot{\omega}(t)+\omega(t)^T \times (I(t)w(t)) = 0
$$
where $$ I(t)=R(t)I_{0}R(t)^T $$

I know that Euler-Lagrange equations are expressed in a local coordinate system of the Tangent Bundle of the configuration manifold.
In *Introduction to Mechanics and Symmetry* (by Marsden and Raitu), they state the Euler-Lagrange takes the form (Theorem 7.3.3), on a chart $U\times E \subset TQ$ where $Q$ is the configuration manifold
$$ 
\frac{d}{dt} D_{2}L(u(t),v(t)).w = D_1L(u(t),v(t)).w, \forall w \in E
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt} u(t) = v(t) $$

I tried to apply this for rotations. The Lagrangian is defined on
$TSO(3)$ by $$L(R(t),\omega(t)) = \frac{1}{2}w(t)^TR(t)I_{0}R(t)^Tw(t)=\frac{1}{2}w(t)^TI(t)w(t)$$

I tried to apply the above formula. I've only started self-studying Differential Geometry so my equations must be messy, not rigorous and completly false.
To find $D_1L(R,\omega)$, I took a curve $\gamma(t)=R exp(t[\eta]_{\times})$ where $\eta$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and I computed $(L\circ \gamma)'(0)$. This gave me:
$$
D_1L(R,\omega):\eta \in T_{R}SO(3) \mapsto \frac{1}{2}w^TR([\eta]_{\times} I_{0}-I_{0}[\eta]_{\times})R^Tw
$$

Similarly:
$$
D_2L(R,\omega): a \in T_{\omega}\mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto a^T I \omega
$$

Now I plug time into these equations. Differentiating the second one gives:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} D_2L(R(t),\omega(t)): a \in T_{\omega}\mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto a^T[\omega]_{\times} I(t) \omega(t) + a^T I(t) \dot{\omega}(t) 
$$

I can't see how I can get the original equations of motion from here.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74742/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321748/2451

Comment: You haven't accounted for the time derivative of the moment of inertia tensor in your math. This is trivial in a body-fixed frame; it's zero for a rigid body. It's rather non-trivial in some other frame of reference (e.g., inertial).

Comment: @Qmechanic I saw these posts but they start from the variational principle directly. Furthermore, I think they consider the Lagrangian as a function of $\omega$ only (no rotation). I don't understand why.

Comment: @DavidHammen Do you mean $\frac{d}{dt}I(t)w(t)$? I think I computed the time derivative: $\dot{I}\omega = \dot{R}I_{0}R^T \omega + RI_{0}\dot{R}^T \omega = [\omega]_{\times} R I_{0} R^T \omega - RI_{0}R^T [\omega]_{\times} \omega = [\omega]_{\times} R I_{0} R^T \omega $ because the second terms is $0$. This gives $\dot{I}\omega = [\omega]_{\times} I(t) \omega$. And we have the other term $I(t)\dot{\omega}$.