# Matrix Euler’s rigid-body equation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, variational-principle, action, rigid-body-dynamics

Define the action

$$S[g]=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0 Tr(I(g^{-1}\dot g)~g^{-1}\dot g)~dt.$$

$I:SO(N)\to SO(N)$ denotes the endomorphism $\omega \to I(\omega)$ with $I(\omega)_{ij}=\omega_{ij}/F_{ij}$

$g:[0,1]\to SO(N)$

How to use the principle of least action or Euler-Lagrange equation to derive something like this (A differential equation with Lie bracket):

$\dot A=[A,B],~~\dot g =gB,$ where $B_{ij}=F_{ij}A_{ij}$ and $F$ is a symmetric matrix with strictly positive entries. (Actually, this is not the true result.)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74742/2451

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2861750/11127